# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of null" Running in Jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have a problem if I run my jest test suite.
Site note, I'm using vue-test-utils.
My vue data looking like this:

```js
data() {
    return {
      token: document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]'),
    };
  },
```

My element is this:

```html
<input
          type="hidden"
          name="_token"
          :value="token.content"
        >
```

If I run this test suite:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
    const csrfToken = 'mocked-csrf-token';
    document.head.innerHTML = `<meta name="csrf-token" content="${csrfToken}">`;

    wrapper = shallowMount(NavbarDropdownProfileFooter, { attachToDocument: true });
  });
```

I get this error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue lies at the selection of the `meta` element. Your selection results in `null`, therefore you get the described `TypeError`. `meta` elements are not special. Remove accessing the `head` prop.

```
document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
```

Comment: Please check, if you have a typo.

Comment: Solved, i ignored the errors.
I have 2 more test suites who import the component, and missed document.head.innerHTML.
Thank you :)

Comment: I have 2 more test suites and they import the same componente. Had the document.head.innerHTML = '<meta name="csrf-token" content="mocked-csrf-token">'; only in one suite